# how can I write if condition in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

in bash regarding "if" condition. How can I write in a script that will check  if a text file is empty continue the script else < perform some command>?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html

Comment: In the shell, don't think of it as "if condition".  It is "if command".  If the command succeeds (returns 0), then do something.  The syntax is straightforward: `if cmd; then cmd; else cmd; fi`. Each command can be a block.  eg `if cmd1; cmd2; cmd3 && cmd4; cmd5 | cmd6; then cmd7; cmd8; fi`. (In that case, `cmd7 and cmd8` are executed if `cmd6` returns 0.)

Comment: what the command to check whether text file is empty so continue the script and if the file contains strings perform certain command?

Comment: `if test -s file; then echo file exists and is non-empty; fi` and `if grep -q pattern file; then echo file contains pattern; fi`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to this:

```
if  [ -s "$file" ]
then
    echo 'file exist and non-empty'
    # perform some command then exit?
fi
```

The `[` is a short-hand for the command `test`.  See the [man bash](https://manpages.org/bash) in the "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" for details.  [man test](https://manpages.org/test) is what I end up using most of the time, though.

If it is important that it is a *text* file, then preferably check the file has the expected extension (here .txt):

```
if [ "${file: -4}" = ".txt" ]
then
   echo file is a text file (extension)
fi
```

`"${file: -4}` means extract the last 4 letters from the variable file, and we then compare that with ".txt".

Failing that you use the `file` utility to inspect the content of the file:

```
if [ "`file -b "$file"`" = "ASCII text" ]
then
   echo file is a text file (content)
fi
```

Comment: This answer is ok, though I'd love to get more discussion about what `[` actually is and a link to `man test` or sth.

Comment: Updated answer.  Missing anything?

Comment: . Also, the OP would have probably liked to see an `else` section... 

Comment: I didn't' because OP says "continue the script"

Comment: Right - you actually reversed the check: if the file isn't empty (and possibly is a text file) "do something". But was worth pointing out. Thx.